# Wix Velo - Container on the slideshow slide is not containing the content properly

Tags: javascript, velo

**Context** - We have a multi step web form on our WIX site that is built using their slider element. The last step of this form has one text input and two buttons ("Add another field" and "Remove a field") so user can add more info in case he/she want's to do so.

**Issue:** - Problem is that if user adds enough new inputs these will go over the strip edge. In one case only these that fit into the container are actually shown, in other case all of these inputs are shown but they overflow on top of the content on the bottom strips on the webpage.

Interestingly if we are viewing the site in preview mode then everything works as intended every new item added by the user is contained within the strip and remains visible to the user.

**Question** - Is it possible to contain the added new inputs within the slider element with Wix (Velo) code, so that the strip height will adjust based on how many inputs user wants to add?

**What we have tried**:

1. Slider setting - "Show content outside the slide" - new added inputs will overflow on top of the next sections on the webpage.
2. Slider setting - "Hide content outside the slide" - new added inputs will still overflow, but only the content within the slider container is visible (elements close to container edge are partially visible)
3. Wrap the slider itself into a separate container - no effect on live site, works in preview
4. Wrap the slide content within the slider into a separate container - no effect on live site

Hope someone has an idea how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying a multistate box instead of a slider. A slider should have a fixed height, whereas a multistate box should grow based on the content in it.